# Font symbols displayed in squares characters

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I wanted to use a custom [arabic otf font symbols](http://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_152646044791913&key=fc09da8d2ec4b1af80281370066f19b1&libId=jh8uvu7w01012xfw000DLkqtm6wsd&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fmuneebbaig.blogspot.fr%2F2010%2F03%2Farabic-symbols-font.html&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Ffonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa%2Fdownload%2FSymbols1_Ver02.otf&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fr%2F&title=Arabic%20Symbols%20Font&txt=Download%20Link%20for%20Arabic%20Symbols%20Font), which you can find a table of the characters [here](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/?page_id=486)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\arbsym{arabic_symbols.otf}

\begin{document}
{\arbsym z}
\end{document}
```

the displayed output of the code above is just a plain square of an undefined symbol.

How can i use this font in my document ?.

Comment: I'm not sure that character table refers to the font you mention.

Comment: i tested the font in the link on text editors, and the corresponding ascii characters maps to the symbols.

Comment: As far as I can see, XeTeX is not able to see any character in the font.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, the font works well installed on my system in text editors, so I'm wondering why it doesn't work on XeLatex (or LuaTex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the font, which comes under the name `Symbols1_Ver02.otf`.

Apparently, the glyphs are not encoded into specific slots and the developers were confident that the operating system is fooled into using the glyphs in the ASCII slots. This doesn't happen with XeTeX.

However, you can call the glyphs by their number in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface\arbsym{Symbols1_Ver02.otf}
\newcommand{\arabicsymbol}[1]{{\arbsym\XeTeXglyph #1}}

\begin{document}

\arabicsymbol{1}
\arabicsymbol{2}
\arabicsymbol{3}
\arabicsymbol{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works with XeLaTeX. There should be also some method with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I thought that the problem was from the font, thanks.